# AABB separating axis theorem, finding overlap depth

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics

I want to detect collision between to aabb's. I want the overlap amount, penetration depth so that I can separate them with this info.

I am trying to understand the below code, It produces wrong results in my case: For example:

for aabb [ x, y, width, height ], [0, 780, 60, 60] and [0, 606, 120, 240] it produces xOverlap 60, yOverlap -23, instead it should have been yOverlap 6.

```js
/*
     * Collision Manifold
     * https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6\
    331#:~:text=Collision%20resolution%20is%20the%20act,allow%20them%20to%20remain%20intersecting.&text=The%20idea%20behind%20impulse%20res\
    olution,to%20separate%20objects%20found%20colliding.
     */
     function aabbvsaabb(a, b) {
    
      let normal,
          penetration;
    
      let n = [b.pos[0] - a.pos[0], b.pos[1] - a.pos[1]];
    
      let aExtent = a.width / 2,
          bExtent = b.width / 2;
    
       let xOverlap, yOverlap;
    
      xOverlap = aExtent + bExtent - Math.abs(n[0]);
    
      xOverlap = Math.min(xOverlap, Math.min(a.width, b.width));
    
      if (xOverlap > 0) {
    
        aExtent = a.height / 2,
        bExtent = b.height / 2;
    
    
        yOverlap = aExtent + bExtent - Math.abs(n[1]);
    
        yOverlap = Math.min(yOverlap, Math.min(a.height, b.height));
        if (yOverlap > 0) {
    
          if (xOverlap < yOverlap) {
            normal = n[0] < 0 ? [-1, 0]: [1, 0];
            penetration = xOverlap;
          } else {
            normal = n[1] < 0 ? [0, -1]:[0,1];
            penetration = yOverlap;
          }
    
        }
      }
    
   
          return {
            normal,
            xOverlap,
            yOverlap
          };
    };
    
 function rect(x, y, w, h) {
   return {
     x, y, width: w, height: h,
     pos: [x, y]
   };
 }
 
 let manifold = aabbvsaabb(rect(0, 780, 60, 60),
 rect(0, 606, 120, 240));
 
 console.log(manifold);
```

Comment: ??? the function returns `60, -24` not `60, -23` and the correct result should be `60, 60` for overlap not `60, 6`. Also SAT is for detecting collisions, not for collision resolution. Collision resolution requires at least one movement vector, without which it is impossible to know how to correctly move the rectangles apart.

Comment: @Blindman67 You don't necessarily need the movement vector. You can make it work with just the overlap. It won't be extremely precise (especially at high speeds) but it's not *impossible*.

Comment: @LucasCharbonnier  ?? Collision requires movement, otherwise it is a packing problem. Even at low speed if two corners overlap 1 pixel left, 2 pixels down, which way should it go, up or right? if you don't know where it came from resolving the collision is a guessing game. It would be better randomly resolving collisions to avoid systematic errors can be amplified when guessing. Without a movement vector it is impossible know and guessing does not qualify as knowing,

Comment: @Blindman67 Yes, it's a guessing game and it's accurate enough for most cases. Obviously, the movement vector is necessary to **resolve** the collision. But you can detect collisions *accurately enough* without it.

Comment: @Blindman67 Oops, my bad, I didn't see that you were only talking about resolution.